# Blank php page served by apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I recently installed apache, mysql, and php on my machine in an effort to learn some web development. Until yesterday, I had no problems with configuration - everything was working fine.

This is my file structure

```
/var/www/html/
    info.php
    phptutorial/
        index.php
        core/(more php)
        css/(more php)
        includes/(more php)
```

Apache is working (status: running) and when I navigate to localhost in Chrome I see the correct directory listing. However when I further navigate into the phptutorial/ directory, I am served a blank page and cannot access index.php. Yesterday the page loaded fine. I think it's a configuration problem with apache or php. The file permissions on my directories are all 755.

Any ideas? I also noticed that strangely there is no httpd.conf located in /etc/apache2/. The userdir module is enabled.

```
uname -a; php -v; apache2 -v

Linux portege-R935 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 10 2015 13:05:59
```

Comment: try applying 777 permission for your project, I think it will resolve the problem you have

Comment: If you haven't changed any configuration after it was all working, then it's unlikely that it's a configuration problem.  Try enabling all error reporting in PHP.  You probably have an error in your PHP code but it's not reporting the error.

Comment: did you touch apache conf files? did you play with any `.htaccess` files?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I realized my problem. In one of my php files I was using require() to require a file which I had not yet created. Mittmemo was right, the problem was the php and not the server configuration. Should you find yourself with a blank page then thoroughly check the php code for such mistakes.

Comment: Actually that is not good advice because that's like finding a needle in a haystack if your code is vast. A blank page is usually a PHP fatal error and checking your error_log for Apache will tell exactly what the error is and the line number if you have PHP error reporting on. That is a better way to troubleshoot.